# How to share a .mp4 video on Facebook wall using ASP.NET technology?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

As per documentation, it says to use Graph API; but there is no example available online, to show the video file can be uploaded from another website to Facebook.

Issues:

1. The video URL shows not supported format
2. API for actual File upload in not able to find anywhere on Facebook documentation

What I tried:

```
string uriPath = "file:\\D:\\Channel_Heart_Diamond_Bow_Wedding_Set_In_14K_Yellow_Gold-FDENS3113.mp4";
    string localPath = new Uri(uriPath).LocalPath;
    var mediaObject = new FacebookMediaObject
    {
        FileName = uriPath,
        ContentType = "video/3gpp"
    };
    mediaObject.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(mediaObject.FileName)); //Error here

    try
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient(accesstoken);
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["method"] = "video.upload";
        parameters["caption"] = "video upload using rest api";
        parameters["source"] = mediaObject;
        parameters["title"] = "my video";
        parameters["description"] = "uploading video";
        var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Post(parameters);
        var videoId = (string)result["vid"];
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException ex) { throw; }
```

If this wrong method, then kindly suggest the proper way to achieve it.
It will be great if you can provide us with a working example link.

Comment: Share or upload? That’s two different things. And where, on a user profile’s feed, or a page feed?

Comment: I want to upload a video on my profile

Comment: Uploading (normal) videos to user profiles is not possible any more via API. (Live videos are still possible, but don’t bother trying to use that for anything that isn’t a live video.)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information